# Python SVN bindings for Windows

Tags: python, windows, svn, swig, precompiled

Where can I find precompiled Python SWIG SVN bindings for Windows?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The (old) [Windows binaries](http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=8100) page at tigris.org contains an installer for *python bindings for SVN*. View the source for the SWIG bindings at [/trunk/subversion/bindings/swig/python](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/swig/python/).

(May 2010 - The *Subversion project* is transitioning into its new role as an Apache Software Foundation, many resources are changing address. Updated source link. )

(November 2010 - more Windows binaries)

The [win32svn](http://alagazam.net/) project, *Subversion for Windows, by alagazam*,
is a win32 build of subversion.
As of November 2010, it contains a 1.6.13 build dated 2010-10-05,
*including `python 2.6` bindings*.

(January 2011 - keeping up: 2010-12-17, [1.6.15](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.6.15/), Python 2.6.6.)

(May 2011 - 2011-03-14, [1.6.16](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.6.16/), Python 2.6.6)

(June 2011 - 2011-06-03, [1.6.17](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.6.17/), Python 2.6.6)

(October 2011 - 2011-10-15, [1.7.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.7.0/)), Python 2.6.6 and 2.7.2)

(December 2011 - 2011-12-12, [[1.7.2]](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.7.2/), Python 2.7.2 and 2.6.6)

(February 2012 - 2012-02-18, [[1.7.3]](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.7.3/), Python 2.5.4 , 2.6.6 and 2.7.2 )

(March 2012 - 2012-03-08 [1.7.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.7.4/), Python 2.5.4 , 2.6.6 and 2.7.2)

(May 2012 - 2012-05-17 [1.7.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.7.5/), Python 2.5.4 , 2.6.6 and 2.7.3)

(August 2012 - 2012-08-15 [1.7.6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.7.6/), Python 2.5.4, 2.6.6 and 2.7.3. No Python 3 version)

(December 2012 - 2012-12-20 [1.7.8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.7.8/), Python 2.5.4, 2.6.6 and 2.7.3.)

(November 2013 - 2013-11-25 [1.8.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.8.5/), Python 2.6.6 and 2.7.6)

(May 2016 - 2016-05-04 [1.8.16](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.8.16/), Python 2.6.6 and 2.7.9)

Comment: These are rather outdated - only 1.6.6 version while the latest SVN is 1.6.11

Comment: thanks for keeping this updated 2 years later. that's really helpful!

Comment: Is there no Python3 compatibility?

Comment: bindings are for 32 bit? any 64 bit version?

Comment: FYI: VisualSVN Server includes SWIG Python 2.7 bindings for Subversion. If you use an up-to-date VisualSVN Server version, check `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%PythonPackages` on the server computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find working bindings in the Trac project:

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion

See the attachment:

svn-win32-1.6.15_py_2.7.zip

Comment: Unfortunatelly this version is not working with Python 2.7 
The error is:
>>> import svn.core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\tools\Python27\lib\site-packages\svn\core.py", line 19, in <module>
    from libsvn.core import *
  File "c:\tools\Python27\lib\site-packages\libsvn\core.py", line 5, in <module>
    import _core
ImportError: No module named _core

Answer (score 0):

The following page appears to be the only one where you can find 64 bits SWIG bindings :
https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/libsvn

You will need them with a 64 bits mercurial install, and the 32 bits mercurial installer will not install on a 64 bits windows.