# How to compile a svn python binding for windows from the source?

Tags: python, windows, svn

I'm setting up a new svn+trac environment, the svn server's version is 1.6.11, then I can't find any corresponding pre-compiled svn-python binding, finally I found the following thread:

[Python SVN bindings for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677252/python-svn-bindings-for-windows)

so, my question is: how to compile from these source?

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/swig/python/

Comment: Do you absolutely need the swig bindings? If not you could try using PySVN which has prebuilt Windows binaries for svn 1.6.6 and Python 2.6/3.1 at http://pysvn.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=1768&expandFolder=1768&folderID=1768

Comment: I've put a bounty on this because I'm also having the same issue. It would be good either to know if there are pre-compiled binaries for this also.

Answer (score 3):

The [win32svn](http://alagazam.net/) project, *Subversion for Windows, by alagazam*,
is a win32 build of subversion.

As of November 2010, the latest build is 1.6.13 dated 2010-10-05,
*including `python 2.6` bindings*.
Builds of earlier SVN versions on the same page include 1.6.11.

Comment: That's useful information. I'm not at liberty to change the versions of Python or SVN at the moment. It may help the OP.

Comment: 1.6.11 is also available on the same page.

Comment: unfortunatly the python 2.7 binding aren't