# How do I commit code changes to svn via python script?

Tags: svn

Configuration: Python 2.6, SVN client/sever 1.7.10

I can check out a repo from within Python without issues but when it comes to committing it I've run into a but of a problem.  My code uses the subprocess.call() method.

```
def Svn_Checkin( dir_path = "..", svn_rev = "0" ):
"""
    Svn_Checkin:
        check in mem_usage_db file.
        dir_path should be the path to a temporary folder
        svn_rev should be the latest svn rev for the input data
"""
try:
    svn = os.environ[ "SVNBIN" ].strip( '"' )
except:
    svn = "svn"

message = '"memory usage db update with rev %s"' % ( svn_rev )
cmd = [ svn, "ci", "-m", message ]
path = dir_path

try:
    username_password = os.environ[ "GENERIC_READONLY_LOGIN" ].split()
    map(lambda x: cmd.append( x ), os.environ[ "GENERIC_READONLY_LOGIN" ].split() ) 
except KeyError:
    pass
except:
    print( string.join( apply( traceback.format_exception, sys.exc_info() ), '' ) )

cmd.append( path )
print " ".join( cmd )
subprocess.call( cmd )
```

My code generates the following string:

> svn ci -m "memory usage db update with rev 6780" c:\users\kerick~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpembglo

I can see:

> > Sending        users\kerick~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpkv1icr\mem_usage_db.csv
> >     Transmitting file data .svn: E165001: Commit failed (details follow):
> >     svn: E165001: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 255) with output:
> >     usage was unexpected at this time.

If I cut&paste the same string to a DOS shell and execute it, it works as expected, without error.

So, does anyone have any suggestions as to a method for committing a revision to SVN via a Python script?

Comment: That error is coming from the server, not your script. Something in how your script is executing is passing something to the server that is different from what you think it's passing. There are [Python bindings for Subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677252/python-svn-bindings-for-windows) which should work better than cobbling together a command-line string & executing it.