# Python bindings for subversion (Tortoise SVN)

Tags: windows, svn, python-3.x, tortoisesvn

I would like to have post-commit hook for Tortoise SVN. I have got mailer.py downloaded from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/mailer/ and trying to get it work as indicated in its documentation.

I just renamed the post-commit.tmpl to post-commit.bat and put in the following lines to invoke mailer.py

```
set REPOS=%1
set REV=%2
set TXN_NAME=%3

start python %REPOS%\mailer.py commit %REPOS% %$REV% %REPOS%\hooks\mailer.conf
```

When I do perform SVN commit, the python scripts reports an error "**You need version 1.0.5 or better of the Subversion Python bindings**".

I surfed in stackoverflow and it suggested me to download the python bindings from http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/swig/python/. But I'm clueless on how to build this for windows and get it work for me.

I've Tortoise SVN and Python33 installed in Windows 7. Please help me to get rid of this issue "**You need version 1.0.5 or better of the Subversion Python bindings**".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/677252/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the reply. Indeed I was lucky to go through the link which you have mentioned. And I could see the support for only for older version of pyhton i.e. up to 2.6.6 and 2.7.6. Actually I have installed python 33 in my windows 7. My apologies if the version would work for Python 33 as well. Despite all these, I just downloaded the version (November 2013 2013-11-25 1.8.5, Python 2.6.6 and 2.7.6) and could see the needed files such as core.py but not sure how to get this work for me. Kindly shed some light on getting the python bindings working for tortoise SVN.